# How to use userData in addToolTipRect

Tags: swift

I am trying to display a tooltip with the addToolTipRect function but I am not sure how to pass the text that should be displayed. The code doesn't work but I think the code illustrates what I want to do:

```
var thedata : [String:AnyObject] = ["txt" : "Text to display"];
addToolTipRect(lsTooltipRects[0], owner: self, userData: &thedata)
```

...

```
override func view(view: NSView, stringForToolTip tag: NSToolTipTag, point: NSPoint, userData data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> String
{
    let pUserData = UnsafeMutablePointer<[String:AnyObject]>(data).memory
    return pUserData["txt"] // how do I get the text ???

    return "hello" // works fine
}
```

I don't know how to convert the [String:AnyObject] back and forth?

Comment: `view.toolTip` https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSView/toolTip maybe? I have never used it, but it sounds right according to the documentation. I think you will have to set that value though, not using the way you currently pass the data.

Comment: @Kendel: Thanks but I think this is something else. I don't want a tooltip for the complete view. It should only be displayed for a small part of it which works fine already. The problem is displaying the right text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The code is working. The problem was the place where thedata was defined. Because only the pointer is passed the variable will be destroyed by the time you use it. So thedata should be defined globally.

Sorry for the inconvenience.